# Sqoop import error -- SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, hive, hdfs, sqoop

***Beginner***

Im trying to use sqoop import from Oracle to HDFS

I get error message -

> SQL command not properly ended , Import Failed : java:IOexception : No >column to generate for ClassWriter

my query is

```
--query "select a,b,c from db.table where date = to_date('9999-12-31','yyyy-MM-dd')" where \$conditions"
```

Comment: 1. Can you pls share full sqoop command? 2. Ensure that the $condition parameter is being passed on correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your query contains two WHERE clause, this is syntax error. Use AND to add $conditions  to the same WHERE, whole query should be double-quoted, including $CONDITIONS, it is the part of the same WHERE, and in your query double-quotes are broken.

Like this:

```
--query "select a,b,c from db.table where date = to_date('9999-12-31','yyyy-MM-dd') and \$CONDITIONS"
```

Check what exactly sqoop executes, does it resolve correctly or not (conditions passed correctly), use `--verbose` to get more information and fix query accordingly.

Comment: Made changes as stated above by enclosing all of the query within " ". Added --verbose too. Now i get `IMPORT FAILED:No column by the name Date Updated found while importing data`   .However my source doesn't have the Date Updated column in it. @leftjoin